# matching two javascript array to form intersection result

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the shorthand and best way to find intersection?

```
f = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]; //might be less than 8
b = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];   //always 8 elements
```

Desired resulting array ["A","D"]

Comment: why `"C"`, at it's the third element in `f`? shouldn't be `D` ?

Comment: Either your desired is wrong or i did not get it.. Should be ["A","D"]

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected the mistake. thanks for notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var f = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    b = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    r = f.filter((_, i) => b[i]);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: *Desired resulting array ["A","C"]*

Comment: i assume to filter the same place.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `f` array is never longer than your `b` array

```
f.filter((item, index) => b[index] === 1);
```

If you're wanting this completely shorthand you can rename `item` and `index` and drop the `=== 1`:

```
f.filter((a, i) => b[i]);
```

---

```js
var f = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]; //might be less than 8
var b = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];   //always 8 elements
console.log(f.filter((a, i) => b[i]));
```

Comment: *Desired resulting array ["A","C"]*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest in my answer I state: "...and assuming you meant D instead of C".

Answer (score 1):

```js
var f = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var b = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];

var res = f.filter(function(e, i) {
  return b[i]; // short for return b[i] === 1;
});

console.log(res);
```

Or even shorter using **arrow functions** like this:

```js
var f = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var b = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];

var res = f.filter((e, i) => b[i]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: *Desired resulting array ["A","C"]*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've noticed and I'm still waiting for the user to clarify! It's is probably just a typo!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It would be totally pointless if the desired result would be `[A,C]`.

Comment: He just re-editted the question It was a typo! As Kind user said there is no logic for it to be `[A, C]`!

Comment: @Kinduser, everyone realized that i was `[A,C]`(not big deal). The OP should have presented the proper conditions

Answer (score 0):

Another Way :

```js
$(function(){
  f = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
  b = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];
  x = [];
  $.each(b,function(key, value){
    value?x.push(f[key]):'';
  });
  console.log(x)
});
```

Comment: jquery goes always, but why?

Comment: @NinaScholz He is probably a jQuery-phobic http://needsmorejquery.com/!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir :))

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, more the opposite, **jquery[philic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-philic)**

Comment: @NinaScholz wanna stop analyzing me ? :-D

Comment: @MajidNayyeri, but you are right, the question has the tag `jquery`.

Comment: @NinaScholz that's it !

Answer (score 0):

Since for loops are faster than filter method i suggest this:

```
var results = [];
for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    if (b[i]) results.push(f[i]);
}
```

Comment: you don't need `== 1` with truthy values.